# counting records of files on directory with python

Tags: python, wxpython

I have wxpython application that run over a list of files on some directory and proccess the files line by line
I need to build a progress bar that show the status how records already done  with wx.gauge control
I need to count the number of the records before i use the wx.guage in order to build the progress bar ,
is this the way to do this and if yes what is the best method to count the number of lines of all the files on some directory with pyhon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do 2 progress bars, one for files, and second for line in just read file. This will be similar to copy progress in `TotalCommander`.

If you want one progress bar you could just count file sizes using `os.path.getsize(path)` and then show how many bytes have you processed/bytes total.

Comment: Ok Thanks how can i know the size of the readed line with python ?